# Lubuntu boot logo still showing after removing Lubuntu flavour

Tags: boot, lubuntu, uninstall, plymouth

I'm an Ubuntu user but to test out I once installed Lubuntu from the terminal. I didn't like it so I removed it but the startup logo is still of Lubuntu. What should I do to remove that completely, including to bring back the Ubuntu loading page?

Comment: do you have dual boot of Ububtu and Lubuntu? later you removed Lubuntu and kept Ububtu rite?

Answer (score 2):

Command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

and select ubuntu-logo.plymouth

Then run ...
Code:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Check /usr/share/plymouth/themes

and remove unwanted themes by running (replace X-Y-logo with the name of logo you wany to remove.

```
sudo apt remove plymouth-theme-X-Y-logo
```

example `sudo apt remove plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo`

**Don't remove the default "ubuntu-logo"**